# Subtract UserPoints from all taxonomy terms upon purchase?

Tags: 7, ubercart, userpoints

OK So i was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Currently I'm running [User Points Module](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints) with [UberCart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) in order to purchase items with currency or use points for purchases. Now i've managed to get the transaction to work as needed except for one small thing. The [Ubercart API](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api) only allows me to subtract the purchase points from a single category like "General". Id like to subtract the points used to buy the product from ALL the categories the use has points in. Does anybody know a way this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You have few options that depend on the number of userpoints categories and the way you want to do it (w or w/o code):

**Option 1:** Create separate actions for each userpoint category within Ubercart.

**Option 2:** Enter custom PHP code and do the following:

- Load userpoints dictionary - `userpoints_get_vid()`
- Loop through all terms in it and subtract the points.

Sample code:

```
$userpoints_vid = userpoints_get_vid();
$userpoints_terms = taxonomy_get_tree($userpoints_vid);
foreach ($userpoints_terms as $term) {
  // Build the params for this transaction.
  $params = array(
    'points' => -100,
    'moderate' => FALSE,
    'term_id' => $term->tid,
    'entity_id' => $order->order_id,
    'entity_type' => 'order',
  );
  // Subtract the points. This will call automatically all UP hooks.
  userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
}
```

**Option 3:** You could also create a Rules action from the code above that will accept `$order` as an argument. This will take slightly more time, but is the right way to do things.

Comment: Thanks very much! this seems like what i need, except one thing. I need the amt(-100) to be subtracted equally among the categories. (i.e -25 from 4 different categories) or (a -1++ that can loop thru all the categories subtracting -1 point until it subtracts the full -100 from all points categories.) can this be don without code i would prefer code as a last resort? thnks for the help :)

Comment: You could do it manually, but that depends on the number of products you have. Otherwise, I think you will have to get your hands dirty and write some code. It should be pretty straightforward though.

Comment: Ok, so where would i put my variation of this code? In Rules Actions, or is this more of a custom module type of job?

Comment: If you want to go with the easiest option, enable core "PHP Filter" module and for rules action select "Execute PHP code". In this case there's no need for a custom module.